# Go line-length-linter: How to ignore one line?

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I get this warning:

> main.go:72: line is 191 characters (lll)
> klog.Fatalf("no ...") //nolint:lll

I added `nolint:lll`, but this does not silence this warning.

We use https://golangci-lint.run/

I want to ignore this line only (no global configuration).

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure but I think `klog.Fatalf()` is nothing but a block of code.

Could you please try the below suggestions:

```
//nolint:all
klog.Fatalf("no ...")
```

OR

```
klog.Fatalf("no ...") //nolint:all
```

OR

```
klog.Fatalf("no ...") //nolint:golint,unused
```

For the reference you can refer this [link](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/false-positives/)